# How to Hide or remove the "Sort Ascending" and/or "Sort Descending" column menu items on a Kendo Grid?

Tags: sorting, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the KendoGrid column menu by default you get the "Sort Ascending" and "Sort Descending" menu items. The user can simply click the column header to sort ascending or descending. I want to remove this redundancy. Anyone know of a simple way to do that?

Thank you in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the Kendo documentation for the Grid here: [columnMenu.sortable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columnMenu.sortable)

Basically, just do:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  ...,

  columnMenu: {
    sortable: false
  },

  ...
});
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Kendo has good documentation but it is not always the easiest to navigate and find what you are looking for.